# Trying to get the first match as a username with a RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't find the way to get the first mach after the slash as a user in every URL request, for example:

```
http://mysite.com/USER/modules/test/script.php
to --> http://mysite.com/modules/test/script.php?u=USER
```

or

```
http://mysite.com/USER/modules/test/path/to/other/script.php
to http://mysite.com/modules/test/path/to/other/script.php?u=USER
```

I dont know if it's possible, but I think it must be.
This is my .htaccess after several tries:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://mysite\.com/(.+?)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://mysite.com/$0?u=%1 [R,L]
```

Where **%1** is the username after the first slash, and **$0** is the variable real path to each script.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor inglish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that the `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable holds the **Host:** request field, which is simply "mysite.com", no paths, no protocols. Then you need to match and group everything after the "USER":

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?u=$1 [L,R]
```

You can remove the `,R` from the rewrite flags if you don't want an external redirect (e.g. changes the browser's location field).

Comment: I trying this solution and it's almost working, the problem is what always get the last /path/ before the script.php as user. For example: `mysite.com/user/script.php --> scipt.php?u=user GOOD!, but mysite.com/user/modules/script.php --> script.php?u=modules BAD!! and mysite.com/modules/other/script.php --> script?u=other BAD TOO!!`

Comment: @e2equiel Added another condition to prevent the looping